How to replace html value from class using javascript console
How do I change the price on a web page without inspecting the elements one by one, I want to mark up the ticket price by 50,000 rupiah using the Google Chrome console with code like the following:
<div dir="auto" class="css-901oao r-t1w4ow r-ubezar r-1kfrs79 r-135wba7 r-fdjqy7" style="color: rgb(255, 94, 31);">Rp 1.430.800<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1ud240a r-t1w4ow r-1gkfh8e r-majxgm r-1p6fy00 r-fdjqy7">/org</span></div>
<div dir="auto" class="css-901oao r-t1w4ow r-ubezar r-1kfrs79 r-135wba7 r-fdjqy7" style="color: rgb(255, 94, 31);">Rp 1.551.165<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1ud240a r-t1w4ow r-1gkfh8e r-majxgm r-1p6fy00 r-fdjqy7">/org</span></div>
<div dir="auto" class="css-901oao r-t1w4ow r-ubezar r-1kfrs79 r-135wba7 r-fdjqy7" style="color: rgb(255, 94, 31);">Rp 1.612.170<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1ud240a r-t1w4ow r-1gkfh8e r-majxgm r-1p6fy00 r-fdjqy7">/org</span></div>
<div dir="auto" class="css-901oao r-t1w4ow r-ubezar r-1kfrs79 r-135wba7 r-fdjqy7" style="color: rgb(255, 94, 31);">Rp 1.691.445<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1ud240a r-t1w4ow r-1gkfh8e r-majxgm r-1p6fy00 r-fdjqy7">/org</span></div>

So the price changes as follows:
Rp 1.430.800/org -> Rp 1.450.800/org
Rp 1.551.165/org -> Rp 1.571.165/org
Rp 1.612.170/org -> Rp 1.632.170/org
Rp 1.691.445/org -> Rp 1.711.445/org

Select the elements and use the DOM API to modify them.

OK, I got my answer.
I run this code in developer console:


var totalClass = document.getElementsByClassName("css-901oao r-t1w4ow r-ubezar r-1kfrs79 r-135wba7 r-fdjqy7");

console.log(totalClass);

for (let i = 0; i < totalClass.length; i++) {
  var hargaTxt = document.getElementsByClassName("css-901oao r-t1w4ow r-ubezar r-1kfrs79 r-135wba7 r-fdjqy7")[i].innerText;

var JadiAngka = hargaTxt.replace(/\D/g,'');
var Total = parseInt(JadiAngka) + parseInt(50000);

var reverse = Total.toString().split('').reverse().join(''),
    ribuan  = reverse.match(/\d{1,3}/g);
    ribuan  = ribuan.join('.').split('').reverse().join('');

document.getElementsByClassName("css-901oao r-t1w4ow r-ubezar r-1kfrs79 r-135wba7 r-fdjqy7")[i].innerText = "Rp " + ribuan + "/org";
}



